Is my Singleton implementation for MysqlDAOFactory correct?
I'm working on a Java project where I'm using JPA for database interactions, and I've implemented a Singleton pattern for my MysqlDAOFactory class. The goal is to ensure there's only one instance of the factory throughout the application's lifecycle.
Here's my current implementation:
public class MysqlDAOFactory {
    
    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;
    
    public static MysqlDAOFactory f;

    private MysqlDAOFactory() {
        Persistence.generateSchema("jpa", null);
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
    
    public PlaneDAO getPlaneDAOImpl() {
        return new PlaneDAOImpl(em);
    }
    
    public static MysqlDAOFactory connection() {
        if (f == null)
            f = new MysqlDAOFactory();
        return f;
    }
}

I think it will work but i don't know

Well... no.
see the problem is you are creating the MysqlDAOFactory instance in the connection method and if two or more threads call the connection method at the same time, then they could get into the if statement if (f == null) at the same time. In that case they all might get true at the same time and create each a new MysqlDAOFactory(); in which case you end up having different instances present in your application.
Option 1: Just initialize it as static field so it is loaded at class load time
Just initializing it eagerly solves your problem:
private static final MysqlDAOFactory f = new MysqlDAOFactory();

it will only be initialized once at class load time and then it will be a singleton.
Option 2: Double if statement:
For lazily initialized singleton you should use double if statement:
if (f == null) {
     synchronized(MysqlDAOFactory.class) {
         if (f == null) {
             f = new MysqlDAOFactory();
         }
     }
}

This allows for still good performance since you make synchronized (expensive) check only when required and still guarantees a Singleton. More info here
Option 3 - Just let Spring take care of it
By default Spring beans are singletons so by simply declaring the class as Spring bean you have Spring take over and guarantee it being Singleton (provided you let only Spring instantiate it - meaning never call new on the class and only @Autowire it)
@Service
public class MysqlDAOFactory {
...


Another mistake I noticed is letting the Singleton instance field be public - anyone can assign anything they want to it and access it without the connection method - Singleton instance field should be private
